# Hiding the navigation bar and date in Compose preview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have the following layout built with Jetpack Compose (which is one of the default generated layouts):

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposeTest1Theme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!")
}

@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    ComposeTest1Theme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

The preview looks like so:

[image]

I was wondering how you would be able to hide the date bar and the navigation bar in Compose previews with the `@Preview` annotation and whether or not this is currently possible:

[image]

I tried to study the SDK and haven't found anything that helps me achieve this, although maybe there is and I missed it or there's a workaround to get my desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showSystemUi` controls this.

Change

```
@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi = true)
```

to

```
@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi = false)
```

Comment: Making `showSystemUi = false` only shows the **widget itself**, but not the position of the widget inside the phone.

Comment: What is the expected position?

Comment: The position of the widget inside the surface.